# Joining three tables with null values in SQL

Tags: mysql, join

I have a BOOKS table, a USERS table, and a RATINGS table (with a book id, a user id, and a rating value).

For each book, I would like to be able to get an array with all the users and their rating for the chosen book BUT more importantly, if the user has **not** rated the book, I still want it in the array but with a rating value of *null*, as follows :

| user | book | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | null |
| 2 | 1 | null |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |

And so on..

The closest way I could get to it was by doing :

```
SELECT u.id as user, b.id as book, r.value
        FROM users u, books b
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ratings as r ON r.book_id = b.id
        ORDER BY b.id ASC
```

But if I try to add `LEFT OUTER JOIN ratings as r ON r.book_id = b.id AND ON r.user_id = u.id` as my final clause, it obviously doesn’t work. Wrong result: it gives me the first rating found for each book, not the one related to the user.

Any idea how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use explicit join. It seems that MySQL has some issue referencing the implicit cross join.

```
select b.id, u.id, rating
  from books as b
   join
       users as u on 1=1
  left join ratings on u.id = userid and b.id = bookid
```